# Select rows in matrix using list in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Somehow I ended up with a list that looks like this `[ 1 36  2 72 37 74]` instead of `[ 1, 36,  2, 72, 37,74]`. How can I convert it so that I can these values to select the rows of matrix A, which is a 5266 x 441 matrix in my case? The output should be a 6 x 441 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't see the difference between your lists (why does one have commas, and the other not?), I think you can use the `tf.gather` function to end up with the matrix you want to get: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather